# Open windows 10 emoji dialog with Win+X hotkey turned off

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys, windows-10-v1803

I want to insert emoji while typing in Windows 10. Unfortunately I have globally disabled Windows+X hotkeys using Group Policy. So I cannot use Win+; or Win+. anymore. How do I use it then? I am open to any solution using AutoHotkey.

[image]

Comment: For those who are reading, I end up re-enabling Win+x key hotkeys in gpedit.msc in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you refer to the following article, may be helpful to you.

[How to Create an Emoji Keyboard Layout for Windows 10](https://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-create-an-emoji-keyboard-layout-for-windows-10-490358.shtml)

Of course, if you don't use hotkeys to insert emojo, the following actions can also be done to:

1. Right-click on the taskbar.

[image]

2. Select **Show touch keyboard button** from the context menu. This will enable the touch keyboard button on your taskbar.

[image]

**Note**: You can also disable the icon using the same method.

3. Open touch keyboard by clicking or tapping the taskbar icon.

[image]

4. Type with the keyboard. Select a text field and type away!

[image]

[image]

Hope the above information can help you.